# How do I return more than 1 value with the same Scanner method?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Firstly, I apologize if this question has been asked before but I could not find the solution for this particular problem.

I'm trying to return two values by the user input, but I get these errors, here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class statistic{
    public static int getInput(){
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Integer value: ");
        int n = number.nextInt();
        number.close();
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = statistic.getInput();
        int b = statistic.getInput();
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at statistic.getInput(statistic.java:12)
    at statistic.main(statistic.java:19)
```

It returns the user input only for it first call (int a), and I get these error messages at any call beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()):

> ```
> public void close()
> ```
>
> Closes this scanner.
>
> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked. If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.
>
> Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been closed will result in an IllegalStateException.

So when you do `number.close()`, you're not just closing the scanner instance you just made; you're also closing `System.in`, so you can never use that particular stream again. So just don't do `number.close()` and you'll be fine. `System.in` is closed automatically by the OS at the end of execution, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Oh I see, everything is working fine now, thank you!

Comment: Why do you keep creating a new Scanner every time you call getInput()? Your Scanner should be an instance variable, created only once. Also, you need to handle the case when the user inputs something other than an integer.

Comment: @FredK Thank you for the insight, also could you give me an example of how I could declare Scanner outside the getInput() method?